How can you get Binder to bind to all ConfigurationProperties?
Suppose we have configuration properties:
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties("a.b")
public class ConfigProperties {
   private boolean enabled = false;
   private String path; 
}

I am using a binder to try and bind the values within an ApplicationContextInitializer:

public void initialize(GenericApplicationContext appContext) {
    Binder binder = Binder.get(appContext.getEnvironment());
    // This does not work.
    ConfigProperties configProperties = binder.bind("a.b", ConfigProperties.class).get();
}


But this is failing with an exception that it could not be bound - even when I explicitly set both properties.
If I use the binder to get each property individually it works though:
// This works
Boolean enabled = binder.bind("a.b.enabled", Boolean.class).get();

How do I use the binder to construct the more complex type?
